# Ipad Test simulator

Tags: ipad, simulator

I have develop an application with html5 for ipad, but I cannot find any good simulator to test, from where I can get simulator or download?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can download the iOS SDK from [iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) and it will contain the iPhone Simulator BUT note that **you need Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6+) to get iPad support. Leopard's iOS SDK does not have iPad Support.** (If you *do* have Snow Leopard select "Device" from top menu and select iPad to see the iPad simulator)

There *are* some options out there if your on Windows or don't have Snow Leopard but these will be for testing your HTML5 in the browser rather then as a compiled app.

1. [BBDemo2](http://www.puresimstudios.com/ibbdemo/) - An Adobe AIR App (so it uses Webkit, same as Safari & Thus iPhone/iPad)
2. [iPad Peek](http://ipadpeek.com) - Web based browser that will likely only simulate dimensions (for best results maybe try using Safari)

Comment: Note - I haven't used those 2 suggestions myself so I can't comment in much detail but it might be a good place to start :)

Answer (score 1):

[Browerstack](http://www.browserstack.com) (paid service) supports the iPad / iPad 2 (4.3.2 and 5.0). They set up a virtual machine for you in the cloud, which can be accessed through your browser. For me this is the fastest / easiest way without owning a iPad or a mac.

It also offers tunneling so you can test your local application in their virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

xcode comes with one.  if you have a mac, it is called iphone simulator.  It can emulate both the iphone and the ipad.